# Wine cannot load programs "cannot execute binary file: exec format error"

Tags: wine

Recently, I tried to install wine1.8 and use it.

However, when I ran wine in the terminal, this happened:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

wine64 works good

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ wine64
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
```

Here's when I tried to run Notepad:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ wine notepad
bash: /usr/bin/wine: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ wine64 notepad
```

and here's when I tried to load winecfg

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ winecfg
/usr/bin/wine: 1: /usr/bin/wine: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Here're the details of my system:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ uname -a
Linux janreggie-T100TA 4.4.0 #2 SMP Mon Jan 25 01:29:52 MST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So what do I do now?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried to follow @mohit 's answer.
This is what happened:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ sudo apt-get install wine-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine-bin
```

Additionally, I tried to install other versions of wine (in this case, `wine1.6`), and it still doesn't work.

If else fails, I'll just run a Windows virtual machine.

**EDIT 2**

I performed a clean installation of Lubuntu in my PC, and that pesky `Exec format error` doesn't appear anymore.
`wine` now works.

My system was the problem.

Comment: What's the  output of `file -L $(which wine)`?

Answer (score 4):

This is most probally because you didn't install wine 32 bit.You can do so using these commands:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

[Source](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Comment: wine-bin doesn't exist.

`janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ sudo apt-get install wine-bin`  
`Reading package lists... Done`  
`Building dependency tree`  
`Reading state information... Done`  
`E: Unable to locate package wine-bin`

Comment: Sry that was outdated. Try the new answer

Answer (score 1):

Related:

`apt install wine-binfmt`